# How do I update my ubuntu VM

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 18.04

I want to upgrade my ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 from terminal of ubuntu. 
I've tried using commands

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

All the above commands executed successfully. But when I checked it using the command.

`sudo lsb_release -a` But it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're looking for is:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

If the system is telling you that there is no new release found you can try to get to the development version with (be careful with this as it may lead you at later times to 18.10 as soon this goes into development):

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```